# GridView inside PageView flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I am new to flutter and in my previous Android app i could make easily any scrollable view inside another with the same direction, working both ways.

I wonder if it's possible in flutter : in this case i have a simple `GridView` inside a `PageView` with the same direction (vertical).

I simply want to handle the case where the `GridView` can't scroll (the top is reached) and let the parent (`PageView`) handle the gesture.

To precise a bit more, in my Android app i could use simply use the Google class `NestedScrollableHost` .

See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011443/how-to-use-a-viewpager2-inside-another-viewpager2/63173653#63173653) to this topic in Android.

I would add that the answer to this question could work with any scrollable view inside another with the same direction.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there is an ongoing [feature request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50946) in the Flutter repo about this.

I added [one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83279) at the time of my question here, but the first one has more upvotes so if you are watching this answer, please go to the first link and upvote the issue

Answer (score 0):

Set your Gridview parameters as follow:

```
GridView(
  shrinkWrap: true, 
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work unfortunately because the GridView is simply not scrollable anymore, but it need it to be scrollable unless the top is reached AND drag gesture is going in the same direction

Answer (score 0):

use these properties that make its work properly. **// important** the other is optional.

```
return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: PageView.builder(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(), // important
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate:
                    const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  // childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                  //     (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
                  mainAxisExtent: 256,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                ),
                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(), // important
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: YourWidget
              )
            )
          ]
        )
      )
    );

);
...
```